# ValueAnimator not being cancelled when called in onAnimationEnd

Tags: android, kotlin, animator

I have an App with functionality such as Instagram Stories. I have 5 bars that are 1 by 1 being filled to indicate the length of the movie. This works fine, also when the video start playing again the bars get resetted.

[image]

But when I switch to the next video and I was in bar3 with the previous video, then bar0 starts (as expected) but also bar4 starts. Switching to a new video triggers `onAnimationEnd` and I want the animation to be cancelled so that I can reload a fresh progress indication. `cancel()`, `end()`, `removeListener(this)`, they all don't work.

```
    fun startAnimation(duration: Long, progressBars: ArrayList<ProgressBar>, currentBar: Int) {
        Timber.d("test currentBar = $currentBar")
        if (currentBar == 0) {
            for (bar in progressBars) {
                bar.setProgress(0)
            }
        }
        animator?.end()
        animator?.cancel()
        animator?.removeAllListeners()
        animator = null

        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, progressBars[currentBar].getMax())

        animator?.duration = duration
        animator?.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            progressBars[currentBar].setProgress(animation.animatedValue as Int)
        }
        animator?.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
//              animation.removeListener(this)
                animation.cancel()
                animation.end()

                var nextBar = currentBar + 1
                if (nextBar == progressBars.size) {
                    nextBar = 0
                }
                Timber.d("test nextBar = $nextBar")
                startAnimation(duration, progressBars, nextBar)
            }
        })
        animator?.start()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is; `cancel()` and `end()` methods are actually calling the `onAnimationEnd()` method. So, calling them inside of the `onAnimationEnd()` method is not helpful.

What you should have is a way to stop the already started animation series. Because it will keep starting the next animation because of the recursion.

Here is the code we want (or something prettier);

```
lateinit currentViewBarAnimation: CancelableAnimation
fun onCreate(){    
    currentViewBarAnimation = startAnimation(duration, progressBars, 0)
}

fun onNextVideoStarted(){
    currentViewBarAnimation.stopOrCancelOrWhateverYouNameIt()
    currentViewBarAnimation = startAnimation(duration, progressBars, 0)
}
```

CancellableAnimation can be a class that just has a boolean.

```
class CancelableAnimation(private var cancelled: Boolean = false){
    fun cancel(){
      cancelled = true
    }

    fun isCancelled() = cancelled
}
```

Now the final touch;

```
fun startAnimation(duration: Long, progressBars: ArrayList<ProgressBar>, currentBar: Int) : CancellableAnimation{
        Timber.d("test currentBar = $currentBar")
        if (currentBar == 0) {
            for (bar in progressBars) {
                bar.setProgress(0)
            }
        }
        animator?.end()
        animator?.cancel()
        animator?.removeAllListeners()

        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, progressBars[currentBar].getMax())

        animator?.duration = duration
        animator?.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            progressBars[currentBar].setProgress(animation.animatedValue as Int)
        }


        val cancellableAnimation = CancellableAnimation()
        animator?.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation)

                if(cancellableAnimation.isCancelled()) return
                var nextBar = currentBar + 1
                if (nextBar == progressBars.size) {
                    nextBar = 0
                }
                Timber.d("test nextBar = $nextBar")
                startAnimation(duration, progressBars, nextBar)
            }
        })
        animator?.start()

        return cancellableAnimation
    }
```

It looks a little confusing but it is the way to go since moving to a new video is an async action.